# Why @dynamicCallable not compiling even though dynamicallyCall(withArguments:) is implemented?

Tags: swift

My code is simple:

```
@dynamicCallable
struct A {
  func dynamicallyCall(withArguments arguments: Int...) -> Int {
    return 0
  }
}
```

This is throwing the error:

```
@dynamicCallable attribute requires 'A' to have either a valid 'dynamicallyCall(withArguments:)' method or 'dynamicallyCall(withKeywordArguments:)' method
```

Not sure what else I can try to make it work. Nothing seems to be misspelled either.

Comment: I believe the method signature is wrong. try dynamicallyCall(withArguments arguments: [Int]) (instead of the ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature is wrong, since the documentation specifies that it must have a single parameter that conforms to the "ExpressibleByArrayLiteral" protocol.

> The declaration of the dynamicallyCall(withArguments:) method must
>   have a single parameter that conforms to the ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
>   protocol...

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html (Check the **dynamicCallable** section)

So you shouldn't express it as **Int...** but as **[Int]** instead.